# Pygame Font Color doesn't Change

Tags: python, button, colors, pygame

I created a button class:

```
class MenuButton:
  def __init__(self, font, size, text, pos, color):
      self.font = font
      self.size = size
      self.text = text
      self.pos = pos
      self.color = color

  def draw(self):
      button_text = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font, self.size).render(self.text, True, self.color)
      button_rect = button_text.get_rect()
      button_rect.center = self.pos
      screen.blit(button_text, button_rect)

      mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      if button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
          self.color = RED
```

And I wanted to make the font color change whenever the mouse hovers but apparently, this is different from changing the color of a button because what I did, didn't work. Does someone know how can I make a text color change whenever the mouse hovers over it? (I can't figure out what my mistake is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the color befor rendering the text and drawing the button:

```py
class MenuButton:
    # [...]

    def draw(self):

      mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      font = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font, self.size)
      w, h = font.size(self.text)
      button_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, w, h)
      button_rect.center = self.pos

      c = self.color
      if button_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
          c = RED

      button_text = font.render(self.text, True, c)
      screen.blit(button_text, button_rect)
```